# @GetMapping doesn't display CreditCards under username. @PostMapping doesn't create a new card for user, it only updates it

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

My User Class looks as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "userID")
    private Integer userID;
    @Column(name = "username",nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private List<CreditCard> creditCard;

//Constructor, Getters and Setters
```

CreditCard Class looks :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CreditCards")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class CreditCard {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "cardID", nullable = false)
    private Integer cardID;
    @Column(name = "cardName")
    private String cardName;
    @Column(name = "cardNumber")
    private BigInteger cardNumber;
    @Column(name = "expirationDate")
    private Integer expirationDate;
    @Column(name = "securityCode")
    private Integer securityCode;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private User user;

//Constructor, Getters and Setters
```

CreditCard Resource:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/geektext/users")
class CreditCardResource {

    @Autowired
    CreditCardRepository cardsRepository;

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    //Displays CreditCard By Username Search
    @GetMapping("/{username}/cards")
    public Optional<CreditCard> getCardsByUsername(@PathVariable String username) throws NotFoundException {
        if (!userRepository.findByUsername(username).isPresent()){
            throw new NotFoundException("User '" + username + "' not found");
        }
        return cardsRepository.findById(userRepository.findByUsername(username).get().getUserID());
    }

    //Creates New Card for User
    @PostMapping("/{userID}/cards")
    public CreditCard loadCard(@PathVariable String userID, @RequestBody CreditCard creditCard) throws NotFoundException {

        return userRepository.findByUsername(userID).map(user -> {creditCard.setUser(user);
        return cardsRepository.save(creditCard);
        }).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException("User '" + userID + "' not found"));

    }
}
```

There is also a UserResource.java , UserRepository (Interface) and CreditCardRepository) but these do not affect the problem I am having. Please how can I fix getting list of cards for User passing username on url. How can user create New/ More than one CreditCard instead of updating the one he has.

Comment: Why should it? Why should it find the credit-card with the same id as the user? I doubt that the primary key for the credit-card is the same as the one from the user. Also terrible use of the optional here (just use `map` and `orElseThrow` in stead of ifs, basically this is wrong usage of optional).

Comment: Why are you asking the same question you asked yesterday at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63110054/when-creating-credit-cards-for-a-single-user-it-only-updates-the-previous-card?noredirect=1#comment111629572_63110054. The comment above and the comments there clearly explain the problem.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the user has already asked the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63110054/when-creating-credit-cards-for-a-single-user-it-only-updates-the-previous-card?noredirect=1#comment111629572_63110054

Comment: Optional use did the Job for the User class. Also the program focus is to obtain a list of cards for a single user, reason why OneToMany and ManyToOne is being used, there has to be column that shares the same value between the User and Credit Cards for it to be able to find the ones that belong to a specific user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are trying to get a credit-card using your userID

   ```
   return cardsRepository.findById(userRepository.findByUsername(username).get().getUserID());
   ```

   Instead, you could search for your credit-card by user. To do this, you should create a method in the credit-card repository interface.

   ```
   List<CreditCard> findByUser(User user);
   ```

   Then call this method from your controller

   ```
   return cardsRepository.findByUser(userRepository.findByUsername(username).get())
   ```

2. The post method has a similar problem. You are trying to get user by username, but passing the userID. Also you set user to your new credit-card, but you don't add a new credit-card to your user. (And change the name of credit-cards variable in the User class to `creditCards`)

   ```
   return userRepository.findByUsername(userID).map(user -> {creditCard.setUser(user);
   return cardsRepository.save(creditCard);
   }).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException("User '" + userID + "' not found"));
   ```

   This will be much better. Test it yourself and change something if I wrote something wrong

   ```
   User user = userRepository.findById(userID);
   user.getCreditCards().add(creditCard);
   creditCard.setUser(user);
   userRepository.save(user);
   ```

   NotFoundException I guess you can handle by yourself.

Comment: The question is how to get a list of credit Cards for a User by passing only the username/email in my case. For example http://localhost:8080/geektext/users/{email}/cards

Answer (score 0):

Update: I had to create an ID for each credit card since if the same ID is assigned on the creation of each new credit card, then program would treat it like if I was the same one that was trying to be updated.